# Does Meteor support Mongo 3.4.2?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, version

in the meteor change log (http://docs.meteor.com/changelog.html), the latest place talk about the mongo version supported is in Meteor 1.4(http://docs.meteor.com/changelog.html#v1420160725), which announced a year ago, and the version of mongo supported is 3.2

I test 3.4.2 Mongo on my local machine, and it works, I want to know if the meteor 1.4.2.3 I used can work well with the latest stable mongo version 3.4.2(https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:versions-panel&subset=-1)?

Comment: AFAIK The only possible issue would be breaking changes in the API still being used by parts of the Meteor API's. I don't think any of the operators changed in behavior in any drastic way with the exception of `$lookup` ( which is not likely implemented anywhere ) and even that change is not really "breaking". Pretty much as always, the general recommendation would be to test your code against an updated server instance and see if you run into any problems. I kind of doubt you would though. It's not uncommon for there to be a lag in "officially suppoted" versions anywhere.